# Slicing the 14th-17th char from each item in a list, then taking an average of the numbers

Tags: python

The data portrays information in a string that needs to be turned into a float

This is what I have:

```
def avg_temp_march(f):
    ''' (file) -> float
    Return the average temperature for the month of March for all years
    with data in f. avg_temp_march('cryer2')
    '''
    newlist = []
    for item in f:
        item = item[14:17]
        newlist.append(item)
        summing = float(sum(newlist))
        count = float(len(newlist))
        if newlist == []:
            return False
        return float(summing/count)
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert to float here

```
newlist.append(float(item))

#And can just use
summing = sum(newlist)
count = len(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what the OP wanted

```
def avg_temp_march(f):
    average = ((sum(f[13:17]))/4)
    if len(f[13:17]) < 4:
        return False
    return float(average)
```